# How to read array and loop server selection and deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, shell-script

I have configured jenkins parameter deployment job using active choices parameterize plugin. In my dev server section have two servers called, 192.168.94.139, 192.168.94.140

[image: array]

I want to read this array input and deploy to both servers. As an example if I select both servers artifacts should be deployed to both servers. How can I read those inputs to fulfill my requirement. Until this point I wrote an array to read inputs but it prints like this

> 192.168.94.139,192.168.94.140

```
my_array=($SERVER_SELECTION)
for i in ${my_array[@]} 
do 

   echo $my_array

done
```

Answer (score 2):

Look this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get servers list
set -f
string=$DEPLOY_SERVER
array=(${string//,/ })
for i in "${!array[@]}"do    
      echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"    
done
```

I found this [link](https://medium.com/@lucabecchetti/autodeploy-from-gitlab-to-multiple-aws-ec2-instances-a43448727c5a)

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way is to use **IFS environment variable** (Internal Field Separator) to define a *delimiter* when assigning a string list to array.

```bash
IFS="," SERVERS=($SERVERS) #BTW, no need to declare a new variable, just reassign

for SERVER in ${SERVERS[@]} 
do 
   echo $SERVER
done
```